# Count Item based on ng-if Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to count number of items in my list based on ng-if .My code is 
like this

```
<span *ngFor="let item of page1Message ,let i = index; trackBy: index;">
  <ion-card  *ngIf="item.item_status=='30' ||item.item_status=='200' ">
```

I don't want to check in .ts file based on if.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: I want to count number of card created with ng-if